# Opening Custom WebView with "Powered By Chrome" With action menus

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

I've recently noticed that when a link is opened in some of few Android apps, they have this similar look and feel and the custom action menus with the "Powered by Chrome" below the custom menu. What component is used in this or is it still the Chromium `WebView`? Hopefully I'm looking to add them to my next projects which involve opening link inside an app.

[image: LinkedIn App]
**LinkedIn App**

[image: Twitter App]
**Twitter App**

[image: GMail App]
**GMail App**

Comment: See: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Answer (score 20):

It is [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs). You can see the sample code from Google Chrome [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client).

Try the following util class:

```
public class CustomTabs {

    private static final int TOOLBAR_SHARE_ITEM_ID = 1;

    public static void openTab(Context context, String url) {
        CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();

        enableUrlBarHiding(builder);
        setToolbarColor(context, builder);
        setSecondaryToolbarColor(context, builder);
        setCloseButtonIcon(context, builder);
        setShowTitle(builder);
        setAnimations(context, builder);
        setShareActionButton(context, builder, url);
        addToolbarShareItem(context, builder, url);
        addShareMenuItem(builder);
        addCopyMenuItem(context, builder);

        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
        customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(url));
    }

    /* Enables the url bar to hide as the user scrolls down on the page */
    private static void enableUrlBarHiding(CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder) {
        builder.enableUrlBarHiding();
    }

    /* Sets the toolbar color */
    private static void setToolbarColor(Context context, CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder) {
        builder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
    }

    /* Sets the secondary toolbar color */
    private static void setSecondaryToolbarColor(Context context, CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder) {
        builder.setSecondaryToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
    }    

    /* Sets the Close button icon for the custom tab */
    private static void setCloseButtonIcon(Context context, CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder) {
        builder.setCloseButtonIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_back));
    }

    /* Sets whether the title should be shown in the custom tab */
    private static void setShowTitle(CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder) {
        builder.setShowTitle(true);
    }

    /* Sets animations */
    private static void setAnimations(Context context, CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder) {
        builder.setStartAnimations(context, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
        builder.setExitAnimations(context, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }

    /* Sets share action button that is displayed in the Toolbar */
    private static void setShareActionButton(Context context, CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder, String url) {
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_share);
        String label = "Share via";

        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, shareIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        builder.setActionButton(icon, label, pendingIntent);
    }

    /* Adds share item that is displayed in the secondary Toolbar */
    private static void addToolbarShareItem(Context context, CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder, String url) {
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_share);
        String label = "Share via";

        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, shareIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        builder.addToolbarItem(TOOLBAR_SHARE_ITEM_ID, icon, label, pendingIntent);

    }

    /* Adds a default share item to the menu */
    private static void addShareMenuItem(CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder) {
        builder.addDefaultShareMenuItem();
    }

    /* Adds a copy item to the menu */
    private static void addCopyMenuItem(Context context, CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder) {
        String label = "Copy";
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CopyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        builder.addMenuItem(label, pendingIntent);
    }

    public static class CopyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String url = intent.getDataString();

            ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("Link", url);
            clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(data);

            Toast.makeText(context, "Copied " + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the dependencies to your `app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'
}
```

and register your `BroadcastReceiver` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application>
    ...
    <receiver android:name=".CustomTabs$CopyBroadcastReceiver" />
</application>
```

Here is the animation xml:

slide_in_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator" />
```

slide_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator" />
```

slide_out_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator" />
```

slide_out_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator" />
```