# Titanium: Open a URL in a browser window without leaving app on Android

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

In quite a few Android apps (e.g. Stack Exchange, Slack), when you open a link it appears in a browser, but as a part of the app (i.e. not on the Google Chrome browser or a WebView).

For example:

**When opening a link on Stack Exchange Android App**

[image: Google Chrome Browser in app for StackExchange]

**When opening a link on Slack Android App**

[image: Google Chrome Browser in app for Slack]

Note that both looks quite similar, so it indicates to me that Android has some kind of feature to do this (like [SafariDialog](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.SafariDialog) for iOS). Not just a WebView.

How can I do this for a Titanium app on Android.

Comment: visit this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44228971/opening-custom-webview-with-powered-by-chrome-with-action-menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44228971/opening-custom-webview-with-powered-by-chrome-with-action-menus) & create an android module for this.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the new module for Android to show web-urls like the ones in Slack app:

https://github.com/prashantsaini1/ti-chrometabs

Refer the documentation, it's very simple to use with just 2-3 lines of code.

**Note:** This module is a part of core-sdk now released from Titanium SDK 7.5.0+ You can directly import this module using `ti.webdialog`.
Refer this new link - **[Titanium Web Dialog](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/titanium-web-dialog)**